# LinkedIn Old Company Insider

Tags: linkedin-api

Does anyone know how to access the old Company Insider? LinkedIn does not show the old Insider code in the Plugins now. 
We have the old Company Insider on our site and need to change it from Popup to 'Always Open'.

Comment: and, your programming question is?

Answer (score 0):

That feature is deprecated. You should migrate to the new plugin.